# Deploying Registry Keys remotely

Tags: powershell, deployment, registry

I have to code a script, which deploys two different registry keys remotely to all clients in our Active Directory. The script doesnt respond with any errors, but it still seems, that the keys aren't getting created. Can you maybe help me?

Im not used to programming so please keep that in mind :D

```
$pc = Get-ADComputer -filter {name -like "WS226"}
foreach ($object in $pc)
{
    $object.name

    #New Powershell-Remotesession with $PC
    $session = New-PSSession -Computername $object.name

    $Dir ="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1"
    If (Test-Path $Dir)
    {
        New-Item  -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1  -Name NewKey -Value "Default Value" -Force
        New-ItemProperty  -Path  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\NewKey -Name "NLS_DATE_FORMAT" -PropertyType "String" -Value "DD.MM.RRRR"
    }
    else
    {
        ECHO "key"
    }

    $Dir ="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1"
    If (Test-Path $Dir)
    {
        New-Item  -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1  -Name NewKey2 -Value "Default Value" -Force
        New-ItemProperty  -Path     HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\NewKey2 -Name "    NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS" -PropertyType "String" -Value ".,"
    }
    else
    {
        ECHO "key"
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing your code is incomplete and your line-wrapping is broken. Does your code look exactly like what you posted here? If not: please [edit] your question and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the pssession but you don't use it.
Put your code in a invoke-command.

Example

```
Invoke-command -Session $Session -scriptblock{
   $Dir ="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1"
   If (Test-Path $Dir)
   {
   New-Item  -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1  -Name NewKey -
   Value "Default Value" -Force
  #your other code goes here
}
```